# Select the DropDown value then Navigate to page using Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to navigate on selected drop down value. Suppose I select first value from the drop down list,then navigate to page 2, if I select another value then navigate to page 3 and so on.

Angular 6

```html
<select
    class="form-control"
    id="mnptype"
    placeholder="Mnp Type"
    [(ngModel)]="optionSelected"
    (change)="onNavigate($event.target.value)"
>
    <option value="" disabled selected> Please select Option</option>
    <option *ngFor="let id of mnptype" [value]="id">{{id}}</option>
</select>
<br />
```

```js
export class MnpIndividualComponent implements OnInit {
    mnptype: string[] = ['Port In', 'Port In Withdrawal'];

    onNavigate(location: string) {
        this.router.navigate(['sim']);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you want to use queryParams and pass in your id? something like this.router.navigate(["sim"],queryParams) where queryParams is an object with page as the key and page number as its value. alternatively, pass in your id variable instead of "sim"? (idk what sim is)

Comment: How is your routing structured and what does/doesn't work right now?

Comment: 'Sim' is path name. I want when I select port in then it will navigate to sim or when I'll select port in withdrawal it will navigate to another page like 'esaf'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
<option *ngFor="let id of mnptype" [value]="id">{{id}}</option>
```

here you are binding value to id but id is a string in your mnptype array, I think you should be doing like this:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of mnptype;let id = index" [value]="id">{{item}}</option>
```

and coming to your question in your onNavigate function you are not using the location parameter inside `this.router.navigate(['sim']);` you're always navigating to relative path 'sim'.
Also you have to change your routes accordingly in your routing module.
Okay after seeing your comment you can navigate to sim or esaf using a simple if condition in your onNavigate function.

```
onNavigate(location) {
 if(location === 'your selected option') {
  this.router.navigate(['sim']);
} else if(location === 'your another option') {
  this.router.navigate(['esaf']);
}
}
```

Comment: Done...thanks, but   <option *ngFor="let item of mnptype;let id = index" [value]="id">{{item}}</option> its not working for me. I used mine code for HTML <option *ngFor="let id of mnptype" [value]="id">{{id}}</option>

Comment: It's not working for you because this time the argument you are passing to onNavigate is a number which is the corresponding index of the selected option, so in your onNavigate function you should change the if conditions based on the indexes rather than the values. Anyway mark my answer as correct if it's solved your issue.